# ASP.Net MVC How can I access hiddenfields from layout in controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a hidden field in the layout page

```
@Html.Hidden("idmember", "123456");
```

I want to access this value in my controller's action

```
 public ActionResult Index(string idmember){
       //value for test parameter is null
 }
```

When I do viewsouce on the page - the value is there.

What is the right way to access the value from layout page? Thanks,

UPDATED. based on the help from others, I released in order to pass value to the action I need to do a form post (and it works) but I have an actionlink

example:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View Member", "index", "member",new{idmember="12345"}, null)
```

This does work and my URL is /member/index?idmember=12345 But I wanted to make the link cleaner instead of passing the value in the querystring I wanted to somehow pass the value as hidden field? or another way to the action? Is it possible?

Comment: if you want to pass some value from a view or layout to controller action, you can do it with form post.

Comment: i think your view is needed here.Also does `Index` method have some attributes ?

Comment: Is the `Index` action the first `GET` (the page the user browses to first)?  ie are you calling `Index` then looking to access the 'test' field that is in the _layouts from the controller's action?  If so, that's not how asp.net-mvc works. _layouts doesn't exist until the controller has run `return View(model)`.  If `Index` is a POST, then (apart from being a very bad name for a POST) you'll need to make sure the `Hidden` field is inside the `form` that is being posted or part of the ajax request.

Comment: please see my question, I hope it is more clear now. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your edit: you shouldn't want to. You pass parameters either in the URL or as request body variables (e.g. POST body).

You *can* circumvent this for example by using the session to store the ID, but this is going to cause unexpected behavior and will break your web application. Session timeouts, users using multiple tabs and users wanting to share links are going to cause problems.

In short: use the URL for what it's meant to do; don't care about arbitrary "cleanliness".